# simplenews subscription form on front page with frontpage module

Tags: emails

I want to place a [Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) subscription form on my front page that I implemented using the [Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/front) module in 'full' mode. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple news block? If I understood your question correctly, then you could override Simple News and and place it as a block.

Comment: I tried adding the block using this code: <?php $block = module_invoke('simplenews','block_view','5'); print render($block); ?> But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('simplenews','block_view',5); print render($block); ?>
```

The number 5 shouldn't be sent as a string.

And if you are putting this in a textarea on Drupal's backend, you need the PHP input filter, which is generally a bad idea.  Better to go through the theming system, add a region, and put the block there.

http://drupal.org/node/1088718

Answer (score 0):

You should `print render($block['content']);` instead `print render($block);`
So solution will be:

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('simplenews','block_view',5);
 print render($block['content']); ?>
```

5= your block id (go to `http://example.com/admin/structure/block` and find simple newsletter block